# The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0'

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, gridle

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0'
or higher to enable null safety.

The current Dart SDK (3.0.0) only supports null safety.

For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

anyone can help me because i give up with this

i actually run it and try but problem of my project got 614 i have done flutter pub get before[problem is 614](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcpIR.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Dart 3.0 doesn't support non-null safe code at all](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-3-53f065a10635#:%7E:text=into%20the%20details.-,100%25%20sound%20null%20safety,-Over%20the%20last). Therefore, using an install of Dart 3.0 means you won't be able to work on a ny project who's defined SDK range includes a non-null safe Dart version.

You need to migrate your project to null safety: https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide. Then you can work up to the latest Flutter version (I'd recommend doing it incrementally to ensure you don't miss anything).